# Python stderr for imported class

Tags: python, stdout, stderr

I am trying to pipe the error messages to a file in my python script.  I have it working fine for the most part.  The problem comes when I import another file, and there is an error in that file.  Here is an example (logger.py):

```
import time
import sys
import test

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self,outputType):
        self.outputType=outputType;
        self.log = open("serverLog.log", "w")
    def write(self, message):
        self.log = open("serverLog.log", "a")
        self.log.write(message)  
        self.log.close()

sys.stdout = Logger("stdout")
sys.stderr = Logger("stderr")

j=0
while 3<4:
    print "Sdf"
    j=j+1
    if j>4:
        print k
    time.sleep(1)
```

The above file works fine for logging the output and errors (when test.py is not imported).

Here is the second file that I am importing (test.py) with an intentional error:

```
import time
time.sleep(1)
print x
```

When I run logger.py, all of the output and errors go to serverLog.log, except for the error cause by the import of test.py.

I am wondering if it is possible to pipe the error messages from test.py to serverLog.log without adding anything to test.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define any modules after:
sys.stdout = Logger("stdout")
sys.stderr = Logger("stderr")

And result will be:
cat serverLog.log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/untitled/x.py", line 16, in <module>
    import test1
  File "/root/untitled/test1.py", line 3, in <module>
    print x
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

My code:

```
import time
import sys

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self,outputType):
        self.outputType=outputType;
        self.log = open("serverLog.log", "w")
    def write(self, message):
        self.log = open("serverLog.log", "a")
        self.log.write(message)
        self.log.close()

sys.stdout = Logger("stdout")
sys.stderr = Logger("stderr")

import test1

j=0
while 3<4:
    print "Sdf"
    j=j+1
    if j>4:
        print k
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that I think you think import creates a new thread. Here are the lines of code that are being executed:

```
import time
<all the code in time>
import sys
<all the code in sys>
import test
import time # Now we're in test.py
time.sleep(1)  # We're still in the main thread!
print x
```

The python interpreter then produces the error. None of your Logger code ever gets executed. The solution, as Valeriy has given, is to put the Logger code before you import test.